# Где смотреть методы java

Tags: java

подскажите пожалуйста новичку. Изучаю java по книге, в ней написано что все методы можно смотреть по адресу java sun, который больше не существует.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно смотреть все функции, например у строк String имею в виду такие как equals, constrain и так далее

Пока нахожу только на русскоязычных сайтам кусками, но что-то мне подсказывает что это всё есть на английском и в одном месте)

Будьте добры, подскажите, а Google по таким запросам не нашел.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: На будущее: то что вы ищите называется `api documentation`. Соответственно, в Гугле можно прописать `java api documentation` и буквально по первой ссылке найдёте то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Да ладно, в Гугле не нашел )  Набираешь в поисковой строке Java String equals (contains, constrain), или просто Java String и вперед, изучать. Название языка не забывай  и все он, этот гугль, найдет

Comment: я ищу так - "название_нужного_класса java doc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете обращаться к [Java API спецификациям](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/api-141528.html) в зависимости от того, что требуется.

Answer (score 0):

Также если вы работаете через IDE (Eclipse, IDEA), то можно сделать не выходя из нее:
1. Правый клик на класс.
2. Go to declaration.
В открывшемся файле будет полностью объявление класса, включая его методы.